# Cannot duplicate node due to constraint violation on an _id

Tags: neo4j

We are trying to clone nodes on a label that has a duplicate constraint on the property _id

```
MATCH (s:part{_id:'aaaaa'})
CREATE (newNode:part)
SET newNode = s, newNode._id = 'bbbbb'
RETURN  newNode
```

and we get

```
Node(52) already exists with label `part` and property `_id` = 'aaaaa'
```

How can you clone a node just changing the constrained property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a map instead of a node variable for the source of the properties to set.

Using [map projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/maps/#cypher-map-projection), we can let that map take all the properties of the first node, and selectively overwrite the properties we would like to replace.

```
MATCH (s:part{_id:'aaaaa'})
CREATE (newNode:part)
SET newNode = s {.*, _id:'bbbbb'}
RETURN  newNode
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clone nodes using apoc.refactor.cloneNodes like this:

```
MATCH (s:part{_id:'aaaaa'}) WITH s CALL apoc.refactor.cloneNodes([s]) yield input, output RETURN *
```

This query will clone your node without the unique properties, so you have to set that properties later:

```
MATCH (copy:part) WHERE not exists(copy._id) SET copy._id='bbbbb' RETURN copy
```

This link explain how to clone nodes and relationships: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/graph-refactoring/clone-nodes/

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mention that I wanted to avoid using too much APOC, my bad. But I'll keep this solution in mind.